# Strcat() returns garbage after strcpy

Tags: c++

Why this does not work? With strcat commented it returns first char * OK, but with strcat uncommented i get garbage characters.

```
char * concat(char* first, char* second){
  char result[10];   // array to hold the result.
  strcpy(result,first); // copy string one into the result.
  strcat(result,second); // append string two to the result.
  return result;
}
concat(rPlayer.name,"blbost");
```

Comment: How is `concat` called? How are its arguments initialized? And returning a pointer to a local variable is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an address to first element of an array which is local to the function which is no longer valid(/exists) after the function returns.

The `first` should have the contents of the `second` array appended to it. You need to be sure that the `first` has enough space already allocated to append all of the characters from the `second` array so as not to run into undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, so the only solution is to pass the reference to {result}, modify it a return void?

Comment: No! It would be much simpler and better to use `strcat(rPlayer.name, "blbost);` directly if you're sure that `name` is well formed and has enough space to contain all of the `blbost` and the terminating null character and check if `strcat` succeeded at all or not.

Comment: The point why I created this function concat is that I wanted to get rid of the buffer. So now I see, why for example itoa() cannot return char*

Comment: It could return char*, but the responsibility of freeing the returned buffer would fall upon the caller.